# PUT Method Using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, networking, afnetworking, nsurlrequest, put

i want to implement afnetworking with put request, but it always shows error when i run it.
it works fine with post method, but when i change it to PUT it shows error.

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:urls];
    [httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"345", @"page_id",
                            @"john",@"username",
                            nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"PUT"
                                                            path:@""
                                                      parameters:params];



    //Add your request object to an AFHTTPRequestOperation
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
initWithRequest:request];



    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,
       id responseObject) {
         NSString *response = [operation responseString];
         NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
     }];

    //call start on your request operation
    [operation start];
```

the error says:

Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 404" UserInfo=0x75a9d40 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}

Comment: Not sure if you aware of this, but the error means that the resource you tried to access on the server wasn't found (404 HTTP Status Code). So the path you specified (none actually) isn't available at all or isn't just responding to a PUT request. You are sure that the root path of the webservice you are trying to access isn't valid?

Comment: Make sure your `AFHTTPClient`'s URL is correctly formatted. As described in `AFHTTPClient.h` ([here on github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h#L57-L63))